# Ошибка TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'str'

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Вылезла ошибка `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'str'` связанная с `+` в части `bot.reply_to(message, text=(f'{user[1]}](tg://user?id={user[0]}, ваши ставки:\n\n' for user in users) + "\n".join(f'{user_roulette[2]} на {user_roulette[1]}' for user_roulette in users_roulette))`. Как её решить?

```py
elif rt == 'ставки':
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(
        'SELECT user_id, bid, bid_money FROM roulette_users WHERE user_id=("%s") and group_id=("%s")' % (user_id, group_id))
    users_roulette = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute('SELECT user_id, nickname FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_id)
    users = cur.fetchall()

    if len(users_roulette) == 0:
       bot.reply_to(message, text='У вас нету ставок')
    else:
       bot.reply_to(message, text=(f'{user[1]}](tg://user?id={user[0]}, ваши ставки:\n\n' for user in users) + "\n".join(f'{user_roulette[2]} на {user_roulette[1]}' for user_roulette in users_roulette))
```

Comment: Очевидно, не пытаться сложить generator со строкой

Comment: На всякий случай напомню, что generator это `(f'{user[1]}](tg://user?id={user[0]}, ваши ставки:\n\n' for user in users)`

Comment: но как мне тогда подставить правильно генератор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка  указывает на то, что вы пытаетесь сложить объект типа генератора и строку, что не поддерживается напрямую в Python.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'str'. Использование генератора внутри  создает объект генератора, и затем вы пытаетесь сложить его с строкой. Вместо этого, вы можете использовать  для объединения строк, созданных генераторами.text=(...)join